# How to work with infinite random graph(s) ?

Tags: graph-theory, infinite-sequences, pr.probability

Hi,

In the case where we are dealing with an infinite random graph (RG with infinite nodes).

How do we model/work with notions like degrees, degree distribution ? How are they defined ?

Thanks!

Comment: Go to the wikipedia article on the Rado graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean countably infinite random graphs with probability of any two vertices being joined a constant? [Peter Cameron](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/) wrote about these graphs in his books, and in his [blog](http://cameroncounts.wordpress.com/2010/07/09/the-random-graph-1/) (there are more posts on the topic there).